# can't resize picture returned by skydrive API

Tags: javascript, css, api

Hi to Evening to everyone,

I have a problem with handling the size of profile picture which returned by API. I tried to change it via CSS, or add them to div container in the body, or append the width and height to the return of API request. but still the size of the picture remains the same.
an anybody point me on what am I doing wrong?

This is the code that I used

CSS part(display property works but width and height don't):

```
#meImg{width:12px; height:15px; display:inline; }
```

Javascript:

```
<body><div id="meImg" style="width:12px; height:15px;"></div> </body>

<script src="//js.live.net/v5.0/wl.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
 function displayMe() {
    var imgHolder = id("meImg");
 WL.api({ path: "me/picture", method: "get" }).then(
function (response) {
   if (response.location) {
          imgHolder.innerHTML = "<img src='" + response.location + "' /> ";
       }
 }
);
 }
 </script>
```

Comment: All that's showing up for your javascript is `<body>`. And there is no css.

Comment: OK, I see it now. The thing you call Javascript, however, is HTML.

Comment: wait a moment there ia s nasty bag here I can insert the whole code

Comment: Could you make a jsfiddle for this?

Comment: here you go. barely manage to insert the whole code

Comment: I'm using Skydrive API to fetch the picture

Comment: I really can't understand what am i doing wrong

Comment: I updated my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be setting the `width` and `height` on an `<img>` tag, not on a `<div>`.

EDIT: OP seems to be adding javascript to the post, that might change things.

EDIT 2: Ok, it looks like I was right to begin with. If you want to style the image with CSS, you need to call the `<img>` tag directly with it, not a containing `<div>`. Add an `id` or `class` to the `<img>` tag and then call the CSS on that instead.

Comment: I've tried to append those in API rerturn. But the thing is it just returns it as a text

Comment: I did this`imgHolder.innerHTML = "<img src='" + response.location + "' width='12 height='15' /> ";`

Comment: Well, the syntax there is bad because you don't have an apostrophe after `12`. You shouldn't be using attributes for height and width anyhow.

Comment: wait I will try to do it but I''m not sure if it will work because I'm assigning the return of api to the div with thw same id name here `var imgHolder = id("meImg");`

Comment: but let me try it. hold on a minute

Comment: Yes you were quite right. Thank you Very much. It's working now.

Comment: I did this `imgHolder.innerHTML = "<img class='pists' src='" + response.location + "' /> ";` Ans set size in pics class. Thanks again